# Number of Discontinuous points

Tags: calculus

How to find number of points discontinuous in a certain interval?

---

$f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix} -x, x< 1\\ 1+x ,x\geq 1 \end{matrix}\right.$

$g(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix} 1-x, x\leq 0\\ x ^{2} ,x> 0 \end{matrix}\right.$

Then function composition $gof\left ( x \right )=g\left ( f\left ( x \right ) \right )$, how many discontinuous points are there?

---

Here x=1 and x=0 both discontinuous??

Comment: Yes, $0$ and $1$ are the discontinuity points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little difficult to count points of discontinuity of compositions of functions, without simply composing them. If $f$ has a discontinuity at $x_0$, it doesn't necessarily mean $g \circ f$ has a discontinuity (or at all!). So, let's compute $(g \circ f)(x)$.

First case: suppose $x < 1$. Then $f(x) = -x$, so
$$g(f(x)) = g(-x) = \begin{cases} 1 + x & \text{if }-x \le 0 \\ (-x)^2 & \text{if } -x > 0\end{cases} = \begin{cases} 1 + x & \text{if }x \ge 0 \\ x^2 & \text{if } x < 0.\end{cases}$$

Second case: suppose $x \ge 1$. Then $f(x) = 1 + x$, so
$$g(f(x)) = g(1 + x) = \begin{cases} 1 - (1 + x) & \text{if }1 + x \le 0 \\ (1 + x)^2 & \text{if } 1 + x > 0\end{cases} = \begin{cases} -x & \text{if } x \le -1 \\ (1 + x)^2 & \text{if } x > -1.\end{cases}$$

However, remember in the second case, $x \ge 1$, so the $x \le -1$ case can never happen, and the $x > -1$ case becomes $x \ge 1$. Thus, for general $x \in \Bbb{R}$,
$$g(f(x)) = \begin{cases} 1 + x & \text{if }0 \le x < 1 \\ x^2 & \text{if } x < 0 \\
(1 + x)^2 & \text{if }x \ge 1.\end{cases}$$
From this we see two possible discontinuities: $0$ and $1$. We can see these are indeed discontinuities by testing one-sided limits, and verifying that they do not agree, in both cases.

Thus, as you said, there are two discontinuities: $x = 0$ and $x = 1$.

Comment: Is there no discontinuities for $x=2$ or $x=3$?

Comment: @Srestha No there isn't. Around $x = 2$ and $x = 3$, $g \circ f$ resembles the continuous function $(1 + x)^2$.